# Change the div:after border right color by jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

How to change border right color to class:after

this css the normal

```
.profile-options a div:after {
border-color: transparent #999999 transparent transparent;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 18px;
content: "";
display: block;
left: -15px;
margin-top: -33px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 999;}
```

and I need to set the #999999 to #333333 when selected by jquery

I tried those but it seems not working

```
$(".profile-options a div:after").css({"borderRightColor":"#999"});
$(".yourOptions1:after").css({"borderRightColor":"#333"});
```

Comment: jQuery does'nt have access to your pseudo elements, only the real ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant change the style of the (:after) by using JQuery.
but you can solve it by inserting DIV in HTML after the DIV that you use
then you can handle it using JQuery

```
<div class="mydiv_1"></div> <div class="after_div"></div>
<div class="mydiv_2"></div>  <div class="after_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `styleSheets`.

Let's say you have one style sheet, and that rule is the first rule, then all you need to do:

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.borderRightColor="#333333";
```

[**All you need to know about StyleSheets, Add, Remove, Alter, both IE and other Browsers**](http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/stylesheet.shtml)

Using styleSheets allows you to add css Rules concerning pseudo-elements as well.