# Access the css ":after" selector with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I have the following css:

```
.pageMenu .active::after {
    content: '';
    margin-top: -6px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-top: 14px solid white;
    border-left: 14px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 14px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

I'd like to change the border-width of the top, left, and bottom border using jQuery. What selector to I use to access this element? I tried the following but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
$('.pageMenu .active:after').css(
        {
            'border-top-width': '22px',
            'border-left-width': '22px',
            'border-right-width': '22px'
        }
    )
```

Comment: Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-using-jquery-e-g-before-and-after

Comment: You can't via JQuery, but you can with JavaScirpt (Accessing CSS Rules) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087736/change-the-divafter-border-right-color-by-jquery/15088868#15088868

Comment: @AliBassam What you just said makes no sense. jQuery IS Javascript (Actually, a convention library for it, but I hope you get the point).

Comment: Here's a superb solution with multiple options, including @blazemonger's below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-using-jquery-e-g-before-and-after

Answer (score 339, accepted):

You can't manipulate `:after`, because it's not technically part of the DOM and therefore is inaccessible by any JavaScript. But you *can* add a new class with a new `:after` specified.

CSS:

```
.pageMenu .active.changed:after { 
/* this selector is more specific, so it takes precedence over the other :after */
    border-top-width: 22px;
    border-left-width: 22px;
    border-right-width: 22px;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.pageMenu .active').toggleClass('changed');
```

---

**UPDATE:** while it's impossible to *directly* modify the `:after` content, there are ways to read and/or override it using JavaScript. See **["Manipulating CSS pseudo-elements using jQuery (e.g. :before and :after)"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21709814/901048)** for a comprehensive list of techniques.

Comment: Here is a great article with three options for editing pseudo-elements in js. https://pankajparashar.com/posts/modify-pseudo-elements-css/

Comment: @Kamlesh you can use this link instead... https://web.archive.org/web/20170715014139/https://pankajparashar.com/posts/modify-pseudo-elements-css/

Answer (score 72):

You can add style for **:after** a like html code.
**For example:**

```
var value = 22;
body.append('<style>.wrapper:after{border-top-width: ' + value + 'px;}</style>');
```

Comment: In jQuery: `$( "<style>.wrapper:after { border-top-width: " + value + "px; }</style>" ).appendTo( "head" )`

Answer (score 14):

If you use jQuery built-in `after()` with empty value it will create a dynamic object that will match your `:after` CSS selector.

```
$('.active').after().click(function () {
    alert('clickable!');
});
```

See the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/after/).

Comment: this doesn't work, nice idea though

Comment: This works for me in Firefox, Chrome and Safari

Comment: Doesnt work for CSS but lets me target the click event on a the :after tag

Comment: jquery after is not meant to manipulate ":after" css property, but the element itself.

Comment: your link to jQuery documentation explains that your response is just wrong

Comment: As Jan said, you link explain that you're wrong

Comment: this always returns "alert('clickable!');" either selector element has after element or not. Not working.