# Jquery :after selector is this possible?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I have menu script I have html something like this

```
<ul class="cbp-tm-submenu" style="left: 50px;">
    <li><a href="#" class="cbp-tm-icon-screen">Sorrel desert</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="cbp-tm-icon-mail">Raisin kakadu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="cbp-tm-icon-contract">Plum salsify</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="cbp-tm-icon-pencil">Bok choy celtuce</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="cbp-tm-icon-article">Onion endive</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="cbp-tm-icon-clock">Bitterleaf</a></li>
    :after <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
</ul>
```

Now its class

```
.cbp-tm-submenu:after {
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;

}
```

And output is something like this:

[image]

Now problem is arrow which is generated by ***:after*** class Now what is want to is i want to adjust that arrow in right as arrow is too left i want show arrow below sale so i want to select **:after class in jquery is this possible? how?**

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17789110/2388219 and that should help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manipulating CSS pseudo-elements using jQuery (e.g. :before and :after)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-using-jquery-e-g-before-and-after)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't select **:after** since it is not a DOM element, but a **CSS pseudo element**.

Comment: Thanks lord but how can i do this there should be some logic

Comment: Your question is not clear. The image does not show any arrows. If you can elaborate your question it will be a help.