# Changing the background colour of an :after - JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to change the colour of an :after, using JQuery although I just can't seem to be able to change it, can anybody point me in the right direction please?

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $( ".breadcrumb li:nth-child(1) a" ).css({'background-color' : '#f00'}); // Works
        $( ".breadcrumb li:nth-child(1):after " ).css({'background-color' : '#f00'}); // Does not work?
    });
</script>
```

I've tried using a few selectors but I just cannot find the correct one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this `$( ".breadcrumb li:nth-child(1)").after($( ".breadcrumb li:nth-child(1)").css({'background-color' : '#f00'}));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

**CSS**

```
.li-active-after a{background-color : #f00; }
.li-active-after:after{background-color : #f00; }
```

**Jquery**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".breadcrumb li").removeClass('li-active-after');
    $(".breadcrumb li:nth-child(1)").addClass('li-active-after');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

> You can't manipulate :after, because it's not technically part of the DOM and therefore is inaccessible by any JavaScript. But you can add a new class with a new :after specified.

CSS

```
.breadcrumb li:nth-child(1) .test:after { 
    border-top-width: 22px;
    border-left-width: 22px;
    border-right-width: 22px;
}
```

JS

```
$('.breadcrumb li:nth-child(1)').toggleClass('test');
```

[Taken from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17789110/2471423)

Comment: If this answer is useful please up-vote the original!

Answer (score 0):

You cant change the style of the (:after) by using JQuery. but you can solve it by inserting DIV in HTML after the DIV that you use then you can handle it using JQuery

```
<div class="mydiv_1"></div> <div class="after_div"></div>
<div class="mydiv_2"></div>  <div class="after_div"></div>
```

You can adapt this example to your code/script ;)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding another div to replace :after or using other selectors, there is a better solution just by using class. Here it is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3QuJJ/)
Click the gray box and it will add a `class` to div, which will change the color of its `:after`