# Select the pseudo class :after

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can i select the pseudo class `:after` of `this` ?

I try

```
$( this ).find( ':after' ).css("display","block");
```

but it didn't work !

Comment: fiddle please..and its not understandable what you want

Comment: I don't think you can do this. `:before` and `:after` pseudo-classes don't exist in the DOM.

Comment: Duplicate of [Access the css ":after" selector with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788990/access-the-css-after-selector-with-jquery) and [Manipulating CSS pseudo-elements using jQuery (e.g. :before and :after)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-using-jquery-e-g-before-and-after/21709814)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to select pseudoclass directly in jQuery as it isn't a part of DOM

You can append the `<style>` though:

```
$('head').append('<style>element:before{ /* apply styles here */ }</style>');
```