# Not Able to Select After Content

Tags: jquery

Can you please take a look at this demo and let me know why I am not able to select the after content

```js
$("#yellow::after").on("click", function(){
    alert("The after was clicked.");
});
```

```css
div{background:yellow; height:200px; width:200px; margin-left:-210px;}
div::after {
  content: "Content";
    background-color:red;
   margin-left:200px;
    
    padding:15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="yellow">
  hi
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788990/access-the-css-after-selector-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$("#yellow").after().on("click", function(){
alert("The after was clicked.");
});
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/Lx65bwzt/1/