# How to animate an ":after" using CSS or jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a menu that lools like this: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NLChW/300/).

```js
$(".squ").click(function() {
  $('.pen').addClass('squ');
  $('.pen').removeClass('pen');
  $(this).removeClass("squ");
  $(this).addClass("pen");
});
```

```css
.squ {
  background-color: #0266B4;
  width: 188px;
  height: 21px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: table;
  margin: 7px 0 0 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
.squ:hover {
  background-color: #419EE6;
}
.squ p {
  margin: 0;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.sec1 .squ {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.pen {
  background-color: #419EE6;
  width: 188px;
  height: 21px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: table;
  margin: 7px 0 0 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.pen p {
  margin: 0;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 30px;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  cursor: default;
}
.pen:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 11px solid transparent;
  border-left: 22px solid #419EE6;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pen">
  <p id="e-w" onclick="checkDisableCbs(this.id);">banana</p>
</div>

<div class="squ">
  <p id="qin" onclick="checkDisableCbs(this.id);">apple</p>
</div>
```

When clicking on one of the list items I switch between 2 classes. 
The selected one gets a class (`.pen`) that has an `:after` (CSS) that looks like an arrow.

How can I animate it as if it's going out of the div (from left to right)

Comment: You can't access pseudoelements with javascript, which makes this a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788990/access-the-css-after-selector-with-jquery), but as you're also asking for solutions in CSS, maybe someone has a working answer.

Comment: @adeneo Yes, you are right. I **made** it.

Comment: Kindly check if my answer is what you are trying to do?

Comment: @ElectricWizard Kindly check my answer and respond. Please accept if it is something that you think. `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to already have it defined. And then use the `position` to animate. `display` and similar things cannot be animated (see [CSS Animatable Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties)). Also what you are trying to do is similar to bringing something from `display: none` to `display: block`.

So what I am doing here is:

1. Change `.pen p::after` to `p::after` with `z-index: -1` and `right: 15px`, a value more than its width.
2. Animate the `right` property to `right: 15px;` or somewhere it correctly matches.
3. Corrected the `top: 0;` property.
4. To make this **working always**, delegate the events to the possible static parent. You are assigning to the `class`, which changes from clicking. So it is **not static**.

**Working Snippet**

```js
$(document).on("click", ".squ", function () {
  $('.pen').addClass('squ');
  $('.pen').removeClass('pen');
  $(this).removeClass("squ");
  $(this).addClass("pen");
});
```

```css
.squ {
  background-color: #0266B4;
  width: 188px;
  height: 21px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: table;
  margin: 7px 0 0 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.squ:hover {
  background-color: #419EE6;
}

.squ p {
  margin: 0;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.sec1 .squ {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pen {
  background-color: #419EE6;
  width: 188px;
  height: 21px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: table;
  margin: 7px 0 0 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.pen p {
  margin: 0;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 30px;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  cursor: default;
}

p::after {
  content: '';
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 11px solid transparent;
  border-left: 22px solid #419EE6;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  right: 15px;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
}

.pen p::after {
  right: -20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pen">
  <p id="e-w" onclick="checkDisableCbs(this.id);">banana</p>
</div>
<div class="squ">
  <p id="qin" onclick="checkDisableCbs(this.id);">apple</p>
</div>
```