# add css to children element before css from jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to add class from jquery to a selected element ::before CSS element. How would I do that? any help?

Here's a screenshot.

[image]

I want to add CSS for the above element from jquery.

Comment: Add necessary code and describe your issue properly. Do you want to add `::before` from jQuery ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

same question here:
[Access the css ":after" selector with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788990/access-the-css-after-selector-with-jquery)

you have to add a class directly to the element and then style it´s **:before**

example 
html:

```
<div>
  text
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.before-styling::before{
  content:'before';
}
```

JS:

```
$("div").addClass('before-styling');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gpydysgm/