# Remove an ::after CSS style using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a CSS file that specifies an `:after` style against a class ('`view-performance`')

Using jQuery (because my JS file contains the business logic), how can I remove the `:after` style based on the business logic?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**You cannot reach pseudo elements using jQuery!**

But you can do it with **css**, and manipulate it using `.addClass()` / `.removeClass()`

**Here is an example how can you remove pseudo element `:after` by adding css class:**

Your JS:

```
$('.view-performance').addClass('without-after-element');
```

Your CSS:

```
.view-performance:after {
  content: 'i go after';
}
.view-performance.without-after-element:after {
  content: none;
}
```

You may also check this question:

[stackoverflow.com/questions/17788990/access-the-css-after-selector-with-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788990/access-the-css-after-selector-with-jquery)

Answer (score -2):

```
$('.view-performance:after').css('display','none');
```