# JQuery modify body content after div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have my code which have a header. I want to modify the whole page except the header. I need to use **html()** and not append/prepend/etc.

Code looks like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="header">
        HEADER
    </div>
    <!-- MODIFY THIS -->
</body>
```

I have tried this but no luck `$("body .header:after").html("TEST");`

Is it possible ?

PS: Dont add any div. I just want to select and modify whole content after the header class.

[**JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/um721cq1/)

Comment: You can't use `:after` in jQuery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788990/access-the-css-after-selector-with-jquery

Comment: JSfiddle is empty.

Comment: @SoorajChandran here is it https://jsfiddle.net/um721cq1/

Comment: @PranavCBalan my question is different. Take a look of it. If it's duplicate, then how can I capture the content after specific div?

Comment: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b3cdujdk/) check the demo if this the intended output\

Comment: Is it possible without using $('.header')[0].outerHTML?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. Get the content in the header , and then use it to populate entire body tag.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 
  var content = jQuery(".header").text();
  jQuery("body").html("<div class='header'>"+content+"</div>" + 'modified content');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    HEADER
  </div>
  Some random content
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `:after` in jQuery and your problem is that there isn't actually anything to select if you don't select the header - your entire document is the body tag, followed by the header.

If there is nothing to select, there is nothing to use `html()` on.

You will need to add at least one div, or insert the header as part of your `html()` for the body:

```js
$("div:not(.header)").html("Body");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        HEADER
    </div>
    <div><!-- MODIFY THIS --></div>
</body>
```

Or you could just use `append()` because it was *designed* to do exactly this:

```js
$("body").append("<div>Body</div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        HEADER
    </div>
    <!-- MODIFY THIS -->
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks but i badly need to use html()

Comment: I saw that in your initial post, but I don't understand why. The point is that there is nothing to select if that is your entire document. You can only append, or add an extra element to use the `html()` on.

Comment: I updated the answer to show how simple it becomes once you add the extra div.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
$("body").html(document.getElementsByClassName("header")[0].outerHTML + "TEST");
```

Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

`.html()` is replace all element with new element.So you can try jQuery insertAfter method.

```js
$( "<p>Your HTML Code Here</p>" ).insertAfter( ".header" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        HEADER
    </div>
    <!-- MODIFY THIS -->
</body>
```