# jQuery select CSS ( .bg-image:before ) in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> (new edit) If you say duplicate of another question, can you give me a solution
>   of my question, I cant solve my problem in that question
>
> since my previous question had marked as duplicate question, but there
>   is different, that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin) cannot solve my problem, so I re-post my
>   question here. If you think you can solve my problem via the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin), please write the answer here. Thanks!

In my .html

```
<header class="bg-image">
...

<style>
    .bg-image:before {
        ...
        background: #333 url("1.jpg") no-repeat top center;
    }
</style>

</header>
```

and now I want to change the "1.jpg" to "2.jpg" using jQuery but I cannot select ".bg-image:before" to change it

In case I must use the above style code in html to do an effect
How can I change to "2.jpg" using jQuery?

Comment: No you cannot target :before, :after  Read here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788990/access-the-css-after-selector-with-jquery)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements such as ::before and ::after using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin)

Comment: Read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21709814/4305494). It does exactly what you are asking.

Comment: thank you @Ricky, I solved from the answer