# How to click on pseudo element using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

How to click on the pseudo Element using jQuery I'm unable to click on before element to change the background color:

```js
$(".box:before").on('click',function(){
    (".box h1").css("background-color","red");
    });
```

```css
.box:before{
    content:"";
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
    <h1>hello</h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please work on your question format. Make it look normal, and describe the problem and show what you have done to solve it.

Comment: don't even think about it. You can't click on a pseudo element

Answer (score 1):

First of all you've missed the `$` sign in this instruction:

```
  (".box h1").css("background-color","red");
```

> Then you can't manipulate `:after`, because it's not technically part
>   of the DOM and therefore is inaccessible by any JavaScript. But you
>   can add a new class with a new `:after` specified.

[SOURCE: Access the css “:after” selector with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788990/access-the-css-after-selector-with-jquery)

Please check & run the following code snippet for an alternative solution:

```js
$(".box").on('click',function(){
    $(".box h1").css("background-color","red");
    });
```

```css
.box:before{
    content:"";
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
    <h1>hello</h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: wrong, you better know about .before() before making this answer. See http://api.jquery.com/before/