# Change CSS Content Property with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to replace the "content" inside the div for run an A/B test.

Now I have this HTML:

```
<p class="flag off-10- product">
```

In the CSS I have ::before and ::after:

```
::before

content:' ';

::after

content:'XXXX% OFF'
```

And the jQuery:

```
$('.flag off-10- product').attr('content','New XXXX off%');
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788990/access-the-css-after-selector-with-jquery this wil help you out.

Comment: Try this below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin