# How to change the color of 3 diferent tooltip arrows

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I made that 3 tooltips have a diferent color with js by data-toggle like this

```
<span class="tooltipjs" data-toggle="sin-datos" data-placement="right" data-original-title="some text">A</span>
```

```
$('[data-toggle="sin-datos"]').hover(function(){
      $('.tooltip-inner').css('background-color', 'blue');
      $('.tooltip-inner').css('color', 'white');
      $('.tooltip-arrow').css('border-right-color', 'blue');
      
  });
```

In this prototype works fine, the arrows match with the color of the tooltip background [jsfiddle prototype](https://jsfiddle.net/3s14btkf/4/) (I set the "border-right-color" in three different ways for testing purposes).

But when i put it in my web app doesn't work.

[image: how it looks on my app]

I can set all the arrows color with:

```
.tooltip .arrow::before {
      border-right-color: green;
}
```

Like i did in thay picture, but i cant change the color by diferent data-toggle as i doing with de background-color of the tooltip.

I search and found that the problem maybe is that the color is set inside pseudo elements (::before) and i cant access with js, i never work with pseudo elements so i am a bit lost.

I alredy try to set it like this...

```
$('.tooltip-arrow').css('border-right-color', 'color');
$('.tooltip > .tooltip-arrow').css('border-right-color', 'color');
$('.tooltip .tooltip-arrow').css('border-right-color', 'color');
$('.bs-tooltip-auto[x-placement^=right] .arrow::before, .bs-tooltip-right .arrow::before').css('border-right-color', 'color');
$('.tooltip .arrow::before').css('border-right-color', 'color');
```

But nothing works, im usign bootstrap 4.

Comment: With your last snippet, are you applying these in the `hover` event?

Comment: Yes. maybe I didn't explain it well. i was trying to say that a try to change the color of the arrow puting that codes where is " $('.tooltip-arrow').css('border-right-color', 'blue');" in the first snippet.
I try all that options but none of those worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be an issue with the fact that the arrow is now generated with a pseudo element (you cannot apply inline styles to those, check the 3 option bellow). I got a few options for you:

- Make a css class with he appropriate styles and append it to the main container (style both the inner and the arrow). For this one, you could define a `data-tooltip-class` attribute, to make a generic function to apply the right color for your markup on hover
- Define your [own template](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/#options), with your own arrow rendering trick (maybe with a non-pseudo element)
- Use one of the options from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788990/access-the-css-after-selector-with-jquery)

Comment: When i start to do this i make something like this https://jsfiddle.net/d3yagbc4/5/ .

Making a css class and define each tooltip, but although it also works in the prototype, in my app did not work, I came to the conclusion that it was because of hierarchy or maybe was the same problem with the pseudo element.
I will try the others options! Thanks so much for your time

Comment: Finally i used the second option, i erased the ":: before" with  `.tooltip .arrow::before { content: none;}` and create my own arrow `.arrow { width: 0; height: 0; border-top: 10px solid transparent; border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; border-right: 10px solid blue; }` Thanks so much!