# How to select pseudo-elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How to select `.class::after` in jQuery?

css looks like this:

```
.nume
{
    color: #463E3F;
    position: absolute;

}
.nume::after{
    background-color: #463E3F; 
    bottom: 0;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

and js looks like this:

```
$("body").click(function(){
    $(".nume").animate({top: "5%"});
  }); 
$("body").click(function(){
    $(".nume::after").animate({opacity: "1"});
  });
```

but `$(".nume::after").animate({opacity: "1"});` is not working

**[Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements such as ::before and ::after using javascript (or jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin)** its now working either

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements such as ::before and ::after using javascript (or jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin)

Comment: Nope that does not work

Comment: impossible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788990/access-the-css-after-selector-with-jquery

Comment: @BriciuLuiza I have personally tried some of the approaches suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin) and they work.
Pseudo elements, like before and after, are not part of the DOM, so it is not possible to select them directly like you are trying to do.