# How to animate a line when scrolled to it?

Tags: javascript, css

I have added a horizonal line after a section using CSS:

```
.section:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  animation: line-appear 1.5s forwards;
  visibility: hidden;
}

@keyframes line-appear {
  to {
    width: 100%;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

I also added javascript into the html:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $(".section").each(function() {
      var position = $(this).offset().top;
      var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

      if (scrollPosition > position) {
        $(this).find(".section:after").css("animation-play-state", "running");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

However, the line animated before I scrolled to it.
Does anyone know how to make the line starts animated just when I scroll to it?

Does anyone know how to make the line starts animated just when I scroll to it?

Comment: You may find IntersectionObserver useful.

Comment: What do you want to happen when the user scrolls in the other direction?

Answer (score 0):

`animation-play-state` *already* has the value `running`, before your JavaScript code even sets it. (Because that is its initial value, and by using the `animation` shorthand property in your CSS, you set *all* the "sub-properties" that you don't explicitly specify, to their initial default.)

You need to *specify* it as `paused` in the initial state:

```
animation: line-appear 1.5s forwards paused;
```

Comment: Thanks. I have added specify it as paused. However the line doesn't appear when scrolled to it.

Comment: You can't directly access pseudo elements like that using jQuery. Toggle a class on the element itself instead, that triggers the animation on your pseudo element. https://stackoverflow.com/q/17788990/1427878