# CSS not applied to an "input" field added by jQuery within a Symfony 6 form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, symfony6

I am a bit confused and I am not very familliar with CSS/JS.
I try to dynamically add an "input" field to my form in order to add an author of a document.
Adding the field technically works as it takes a text and upload it in the database.
Yet the added "input" field with jQuery does not take the CSS properties of the webpage. The field 1 should look like the field 0.

[image: CSS Issue]

I checked in the web dev tool and indeed the css elements are different for the two input fields.

[image: comparison]

Although the classes are identical to the two input fields, the applied css is different.
So that's why i am confused. There must be something else managing the css of the input field so I guess the parent with pseudo-element maybe. Moreover I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788990/access-the-css-after-selector-with-jquery) that JS cannot work with pseudo-element or that we have to use other ways.

Sorry If I ask a stupid question but is my issue really with pseudo-elements ? And if yes, is it possible to update the styling with the newly added element or is my issue completely different than I think ?

Comment: We can't debug screenshots. If you can't provide a [mre] of the issue, then there isn't much we can do for you here.

Comment: _"There must be something else managing the css of the input field so I guess the parent with pseudo-element maybe."_ - the only pseudo thing I see is the formatting for the input placeholder - and since neither of the input _have_ a placeholder, that should hardly have any relevance.

Comment: Classes are different in 2 input elements, one has underscore, while other has dash as separator, might be the reason for differences

Comment: I can't believe I missed it ! I read it 100 times. Thank you for noticing @Prateek. That was the problem.